# What to do if I get std::bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, bad-alloc

Creates `2d` array of organism class pointers:

```
try{
    world = new Organism**[worldSizeX];

    for (int x = 0; x < worldSizeX; x++){
        world[x] = new Organism*[worldSizeY];

        // INITATES world ARRAY
        for (int y = 0; y < worldSizeY; y++){
            world[x][y] = new Organism;
        }
        // !INITATES world ARRAY
    }
}
catch (std::bad_alloc){
    std::cout << "Not enough memory for World size" << worldSizeX << "x" << worldSizeY << std::endl;
    deleteWorld(); // DO I NEED THIS?
    init((int)worldSizeX/2, (int)worldSizeY/2, ants, beetles);
    return;
}
```

if I have `bad_alloc` I want to call init with smaller int values. Do I have to `delete` failed array or can I just run it over? And if yes, then how I can delete it, I cant loop through whole array application just crashes.

Comment: Where is a `new()` or `new[]` you'll need a `delete` or `delete []` to get rid of it in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your program crashes when you try to `deleteWorld` is because your arrays are not completely initialized. Therefore, you may be encountering uninitialized pointers during this process.

To avoid this, **zero-initialize** your arrays:

```
world = new Organism**[worldSizeX]();
```

(note the trailing `()`, which signifies zero-initialization of the array).

Now, when you implement `deleteWorld`, you will have to skip over any entries that are NULL.

Finally: Yes, you do have to delete everything when you get `bad_alloc`: some objects may already be allocated, and so if you allocated without first deallocating, then you will have a memory leak.

Comment: Since `delete NULL` is legal you shouldn't need to skip over zero pointers. You can just delete them.

Comment: @ZanLynx: except that the array elements are pointers to arrays, so by "skip over" I mean "don't iterate inside a NULL pointer".

Answer (score 2):

if you use vector then the destructor will be called automatically so you won't need it and your program won't leak

```
try{
    vector< vector < Organism > >world;
    world.resize(worldSizeX);

    for (int x = 0; x < worldSizeX; x++){
        world[x] = vector<Organism>(worldSizeY);//this calls the default constructor so you don't need the second for loop
    }
}
catch (std::bad_alloc){
    std::cout << "Not enough memory for World size" << worldSizeX << "x" << worldSizeY << std::endl;
    init((int)worldSizeX/2, (int)worldSizeY/2, ants, beetles);
    return;
}
```

Comment: and if its just Organism ***world; ?

Comment: `world.reserve(worldSizeX);` should be `world.resize(worldSizeX);`

Comment: posted the code, tell me if you face problems. In general in C++ don't use new, use vector. It is simpler and you don't have to deal with memory management problems.

Comment: it does not change anything as reserve is the same as resize if the initial size is less than the desired size. But I can change it for people to understand it.

Comment: You should be able to just skip the last for loop. The vector will default construct each Organism. Now, if this was a `Organism*` vector then it would need a loop doing `world[x][y] = new Organism` but that isn't the case in the answer.

Comment: Its is the case world is Organism ***world; :) But thank you so much.

Comment: Program crashes when error is catched and printing out message.

Comment: let me try it when I am back I will fix that

Comment: tried it removing the init function (no definition provided) and it runs smoothly worldSizeX=100, worldSizeY=100. Could you prodived the code that fails?